# Strimzi Kafka exposed via ingress in GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, strimzi

I have a kafka cluster created with Strimzi operator in our GKE cluster. I need to have it exposed over an ingress to allow external team to interact with it for development purpose.

I am trying to expose it over the internet, but i can't seem to find the right configuration in GKE. It needs to do a SSL-Passthrough. Is this supported in GKE?

I tried with multiple configuration, but no IP address is assigned to it.

Here is the cluster configuration that i am using.

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: cmc-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 2.8.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      - name: test1
        port: 9098
        type: ingress
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: scram-sha-512
        configuration:
          bootstrap:
            host: kafka-bootstrap.dev.testdomain.io
            annotations:
              kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
          brokers:
            - host: kafka-broker0.dev.testdomain.io
              broker: 0
              annotations:
                kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
            - host: kafka-broker1.dev.testdomain.io
              broker: 1
              annotations:
                kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
            - host: kafka-broker2.dev.testdomain.io
              broker: 2
              annotations:
                kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
          brokerCertChainAndKey:
            secretName: kafka-dev-tls
            certificate: tls.crt
            key: tls.key
    config:
      auto.create.topics.enable: "false"
    authorization:
      type: simple
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my problem. It seems it does not work with ingress because GCP ingresses are L7 load balancers using only HTTP/HTTPS. So i had to leverage Service Load balancer (L4) which is which allow TCP tunnelling.

Just had to rework some annotations which were in `externalBootstrapService` and `perPodService` and move them into their specific listener.

Here is my new config.

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: cmc-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 2.8.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      - name: test1
        port: 9098
        type: loadbalancer
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: scram-sha-512
        configuration:
          bootstrap:
            loadBalancerIP: <ip bootstrap>
          brokers:
            - broker: 0
              advertisedHost: kafka-broker0.dev.testdomain.io
              loadBalancerIP: <ip broker-0>
            - broker: 1
              advertisedHost: kafka-broker1.dev.testdomain.io
              loadBalancerIP: <ip broker-1>
            - broker: 2
              advertisedHost: kafka-broker2.dev.testdomain.io
              loadBalancerIP: <ip broker-2>
          brokerCertChainAndKey:
            secretName: kafka-dev-tls
            certificate: tls.crt
            key: tls.key
    config:
      auto.create.topics.enable: "false"
    authorization:
      type: simple
```